# In Angular How to pass content type header as undefined?

Tags: angular, httpclient

Following is my code:-

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': undefined,
    'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('jwt')
  })
};
```

But It give me error like -- Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

How to resolve this? And If I dont add content type then it take default application/json

How to call api without header of content type ?

Comment: What was the media type you are trying to pass ?

Comment: I want to pass like {a: 10, file: fileObj}

Comment: That seems to be a json for me!

Comment: It was looks like json but It has file object so it was not application/json type

Comment: use `multipart/form-data`. Otherwise, use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` - i think you can try any one of these

Comment: I tried both but not working

Comment: if you pass a FormData Object as body, angular automatically sets the correct header for you. `let formData = new FormData(); formData.append("key", "value")`

Comment: Make sure you have the same media type on your api - which accepts either one

Comment: @A.Winnen Thanks I did as formData .. first I try By FormGroup But It Dont take automatic headers , then I change it to FormData and it take automatic suitable headers

Answer (score 1):

The default `httpOptions` will be as below. No need of setting `Content-Type` to `undefined`.

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('jwt')
  })
};
```

**Delete the default "Content-Type"**

```
httpOptions.headers.delete("Content-Type");
```

Also send post data as `FormData`. Added MDN `FormData` for reference. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: I try same as you told but It takes application/json type at server side

Comment: @Bhavin Are you using `HttpClient` ot `Http` ?

If you can share any sample in `stackblitz` then it will be helpful for debugging.

Comment: I am using HttpClient

Comment: Are you sending `FormData` or `JSON` data in your post method ?

Please use `FormData` for sending data.   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution with the help of @A.Winnen,

My solution is I first use formGroup which don't take auto suitable Content-Type Headers

Then I change formGroup to formData and it take auto suitable Content-Type and my issue was resolved

Hope It helps someone